# Node Js installatiom

Tags: node.js

I hope you can help me.

So here is my situation:

I have two admin users on my windows, one for personal programming projects, and another for actual work projects.
And vs code and github users are both different as well.

Here is my question:
I have installed a node version for my personal stuff, and for my work project, i was requested to install another version. If i install another version in work project, will it change the version for my personal projects as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That depends on how/where it is installed. it's certainly possible to have separate for each, as well as multiple for each.

Comment: I would recommend using NVM to quickly switch between node versions. I've run into this issue and this is by far the best way to handle multiple node version environments (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you installed it. It is possible to limit installations to specific users but also to expand across the whole system so that all users have access to the installation.

Whatever you did, you will be better off using [`nvm-windows`](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). It allows you to manage multiple node installations and switch between them with simple commands. With such a node version manager, it is good practice to add a `.nvmrc` file to your projects to define the node version used in this project. You can then pick it up with `nvm use`. Don't confuse [`nvm-windows`](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) with [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) itself which only works on Linux/Mac.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time.
Thanks for the answer. It was very helpful